# Unable to get the list of custom attributes from a DLL

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a small requirement and there seems to be some trouble in accomplishing it.Please know that I'm a newbie in c# and this is an assignment given to me i kindly request you all to help me with it with a most prompt reply for i have already crossed my deadlines for this assignment.

I have a dll and there is a custom attribute defined in it i want to be able to retrieve all the methods from the class that uses this custom attribute.please note i have to get the method names from the built dll referenced from another application.

Here is the code for better clarity.

MY attribute class:

```
namespace model
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class Class1: Attribute
    {
        public Class1()
        {}
        public Class1(string helptext)
        { }
        public string HelpText { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

The class that uses this attribute and that is going to be extracted after being built as a DLL

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Assembly mydllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\Windowsservice\BasicMEthods\BasicMEthods\bin\Debug\BasicMEthods.dll");
        Type mydllFormType = mydllAssembly.GetType("BasicMEthods.Transforms",true);
        MemberInfo info = mydllFormType;
         Attribute[] attrs = (Attribute[])info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (Attribute  att in attrs)
            {
                 MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo1 = mydllFormType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
                    for (int i = 0; i < myArrayMethodInfo1.Length; i++)
                    {
                        MethodInfo mymethodinfo = (MethodInfo)myArrayMethodInfo1[i];
                        textBox1.Text = mymethodinfo.ToString();
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

an error is thrown at this line of the code

```
Attribute[] attrs = (Attribute[])info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

which says

> "Could not load file or assembly 'model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The dll is being fetched from the specified location and I'm able to see the class transforms in the quick watch I dont know why this error is thrown... and also I don't know how i can get to access the attributes defined in the dll....Please help

Comment: Somebody please help me read custom attributes from a DLL

Comment: Where is the attribute type `model` defined? Sounds like it is in another assembly which you haven't loaded.

Comment: thanks Stephen for the reply... I hadn't loded the model assembly later i did realise it and loded it however could you please let me know how do i get methods decorated with custom attributes from a dll...thanks in advance

Comment: No problem, see my answer for code that should work.

Comment: i actually have custom attributes defined i don't really know how do i search for the methods that are decorated with these attributes and also im new to c# and LinQ is no exception...Is there any reference u  could route me to so tht i cud find some help...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method should do the trick:

```
private List<MethodInfo> FindMethodsWithAttribute(Type T,Type AT)
{
  var result = new List<MethodInfo>();
  //get all the methods on type T that are public instance methods
    var methods=t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
//loop them 
foreach (var method in methods)
   {
    //get the list of custom attributes, if any, of type AT
      var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(AT);
      if (attributes.Length!=0)    result.AddRange(attributes);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var methods = FindMethodsWithAttribute(mydllFormType ,typeof(model));
```

I'll leave as an exercise to yourself to figure out where in your existing code the above should go :)

Comment: Hello, i find an issue passing model since its a dll, is there another way or may be im not understanding it da right way...., could u pls help...thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, The problem is actually tht since it is a dll im tlking about i can not send model as a parameter since its a dll refrenced by another dll that is being retrieved from an application refrencing these dll's...and also GetCustomattribute method seems to not accept any value other than a bool type...please sugget sumthng....Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you reference the dll containing `model` directly?

Comment: Im not able to load or pass the assembly name in the typeof(),and also the GetCustomAttributes() accepts just a boolean.

Comment: hey...i had to explicitly add the assembly in the refrences for it to recognize the custom attribute defined inside the dll however all i was trying t do was to be able to retrieve methods decorated with custom attributes from any dll's without having to explicitly reference them in the application....thanks a ton for the above solution...and again if there is a way for me to dis widout referncing da dlls explicitly pls let me know....Thanks again

Comment: Yes you just would need to separately call `LoadAssembly` with the model dll!